# Telethon Python asyncio TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable

Tags: python, telethon

you need to get information about the channel, chat, group.
Since each account has a restriction on receiving information, I will use several accounts.
I'm trying to get information, but I get an error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 50, in parse_entity
    channel=entity
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 56, in parse_entity
    id=entity
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 60, in parse_entity
    chat_id=entity
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable
```

Help fix the error

Code:

```
import logging
from telethon import TelegramClient,sync, utils, errors
from telethon.tl.types import PeerUser, PeerChat
from telethon import functions, types
import pandas as pd
import time
import re
import asyncio
from contextlib import suppress
import traceback

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO)

api_id = ""              #(my.telegram.org)
api_hash = ""

filename_excel = "project_for_export_no_formulas_31_10_18.xlsx"
filename_numbers = "number.txt"

queue_entity = asyncio.Queue()
numbers = []
count_thread = 8
def load_numbers(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        content = file.read().split("\n")
        for conten in content:
            numbers.append(conten)

def load_excel(output_filename):
    data = pd.read_excel(output_filename, 'Projects', dtype=str)
    for item in data["Telegram link"]:
        if item != "nan":
            queue_entity.put_nowait(item)


async def create_client(number):
    print(number)
    client = TelegramClient(number, api_id, api_hash).start()
    return client

async def parse_entity(entity, client_coroutine):
    result = None
    client = await client_coroutine
    try:
        result = client(functions.channels.GetFullChannelRequest(
                channel=entity
            ))
        print("Успешно")
    except TypeError:
        try:
            result = client(functions.users.GetFullUserRequest(
                id=entity
            ))
        except TypeError:
            result = client(functions.messages.GetFullChatRequest(
                chat_id=entity
            ))
    except errors.UsernameInvalidError:
        print("Не найден пользователь, канал или чат")
    except errors.InviteHashExpiredError:
        print("Чата больше нет")
    except errors.InviteHashInvalidError:
        print("Ссылка приглашения не валидна")
    except ValueError:
        print("Невозможно получить entity. Для начала нужно вступить в группу или чат")
    except errors.FloodWaitError:
        print("Ожидание суток")
    return result


async def crawl(future):
    futures = []
    numbers = await future
    for client in asyncio.as_completed([create_client(number) for number in numbers]):
        while queue_entity.qsize() > 0:
            futures.append(asyncio.ensure_future(parse_entity(queue_entity.get_nowait(), client)))
    if futures:
        await asyncio.wait(futures)

async def start_main(root):
    print(root)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    initial_future = loop.create_future()
    initial_future.set_result(root)
    await crawl(initial_future)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    load_numbers(filename_numbers) #Загрузка телефонов
    load_excel(filename_excel)     #Загрузка Excel
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.set_debug(True)
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(start_main(numbers))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
            task.cancel()
            with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
                loop.run_until_complete(task)
    finally:
        loop.close()
    log.info("Time work: %s", time.time() - start)
```

In my regional forum, no one could help me, so I am writing here, since the English community is more, someone can help

**Update**

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 54, in parse_entity
    result = client(functions.users.GetFullUserRequest(id=entity))
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable
```

**Update 2**

```
future: <Task finished coro=<parse_entity() done, defined at D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py:45> exception=RuntimeError('coroutine is being awaited already')>
```

**Update 3**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 95, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(start_main(numbers))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 568, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 86, in start_main
    await crawl(initial_future)
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 75, in crawl
    for client in asyncio.as_completed([await create_client(number) for number in numbers]):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 505, in as_completed
    todo = {ensure_future(f, loop=loop) for f in set(fs)}
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 505, in <setcomp>
    todo = {ensure_future(f, loop=loop) for f in set(fs)}
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 588, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
2018-12-27 18:14:49,534 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<UpdateMethods._update_loop() running at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\updates.py:215> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001A379824108>()]>>
2018-12-27 18:14:49,534 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<MTProtoSender._send_loop() running at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py:375> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001A379824138>()]>>
2018-12-27 18:14:49,534 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<MTProtoSender._recv_loop() running at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py:413> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001A3798242B8>()]>>
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object MTProtoSender._recv_loop at 0x000001A37980A948>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py", line 413, in _recv_loop
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py", line 123, in recv
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\queues.py", line 161, in get
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 672, in call_soon
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 461, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
2018-12-27 18:14:49,534 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<Connection._send_loop() running at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py:135> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001A379824228>()]>>
2018-12-27 18:14:49,534 ERROR:Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<Connection._recv_loop() running at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py:150> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001A379824288>()]>>
2018-12-27 18:14:49,535 ERROR:Unexpected exception in the send loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\queues.py", line 159, in get
    await getter
GeneratorExit

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py", line 135, in _send_loop
    self._send(await self._send_queue.get())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\queues.py", line 161, in get
    getter.cancel()  # Just in case getter is not done yet.
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 672, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 461, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object Connection._send_loop at 0x000001A37980AA48>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py", line 142, in _send_loop
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py", line 94, in disconnect
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 672, in call_soon
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 461, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `TelegramClient.start` is an async function you have to `await` it:

```
async def create_client(number):
    return await TelegramClient(number, api_id, api_hash).start()
```

I made two notable changes to your code:

1. Wrapping `create_client(number)` calls in `asyncio.as_completed`. The reason is that `create_client(number)` returns a coroutine object, however `asyncio.as_completed` expects a list of futures. Here is `as_completed` docstring:

> as_completed(fs, *, loop=None, timeout=None)
>       Return an iterator whose values are coroutines.
>
> ```
> When waiting for the yielded coroutines you'll get the results (or
> exceptions!) of the original Futures (or coroutines), in the order
> in which and as soon as they complete.
>
> This differs from PEP 3148; the proper way to use this is:
>
>     for f in as_completed(fs):
>         result = await f  # The 'await' may raise.
>         # Use result.
> ```

2. Changing `loop.close()` to `loop.stop()`. Otherwise loop will be closed and we will get exception when there are still running tasks.

Here is how I edited your code to make it work:

```
import logging
from telethon import TelegramClient,sync, utils, errors
from telethon.tl.types import PeerUser, PeerChat
from telethon import functions, types
import pandas as pd
import time
import re
import asyncio
from contextlib import suppress
import traceback

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO)

api_id = ""
api_hash = ""

filename_excel = "project_for_export_no_formulas_31_10_18.xlsx"
filename_numbers = "number.txt"

queue_entity = asyncio.Queue()
numbers = []
count_thread = 8

def load_numbers(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        content = file.read().split("\n")
        for conten in content:
            numbers.append(conten)

def load_excel(output_filename):
    data = pd.read_excel(output_filename, 'Projects', dtype=str)
    for item in data["Telegram link"]:
        if item != "nan":
            queue_entity.put_nowait(item)


async def create_client(number):
    return await TelegramClient(number, api_id, api_hash).start()

async def parse_entity(entity, client):
    result = None
    try:
        result = client(functions.channels.GetFullChannelRequest(
                channel=entity
            ))
        print("Успешно")
    except TypeError:
        try:
            result = client(functions.users.GetFullUserRequest(
                id=entity
            ))
        except TypeError:
            result = client(functions.messages.GetFullChatRequest(
                chat_id=entity
            ))
    except errors.UsernameInvalidError:
        print("Не найден пользователь, канал или чат")
    except errors.InviteHashExpiredError:
        print("Чата больше нет")
    except errors.InviteHashInvalidError:
        print("Ссылка приглашения не валидна")
    except ValueError:
        print("Невозможно получить entity. Для начала нужно вступить в группу или чат")
    except errors.FloodWaitError:
        print("Ожидание суток")
    return result


async def crawl(future):
    futures = []
    numbers = await future
    for f in asyncio.as_completed([asyncio.ensure_future(create_client(number)) for number in numbers]):
        client = await f
        while queue_entity.qsize() > 0:
            futures.append(asyncio.ensure_future(parse_entity(queue_entity.get_nowait(), client)))
    if futures:
        await asyncio.wait(futures)

async def start_main(root):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    initial_future = loop.create_future()
    initial_future.set_result(root)
    await crawl(initial_future)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    load_numbers(filename_numbers) #Загрузка телефонов
    #load_excel(filename_excel)     #Загрузка Excel
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.set_debug(True)
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(start_main(numbers))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
            task.cancel()
            with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
                loop.run_until_complete(task)
    finally:
        loop.stop()
    log.info("Time work: %s", time.time() - start)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I tried it before, this error does not fix your code.

Comment: Your second amendment did not solve the problem. Added a current bug in the update at the bottom of the question

Comment: @danilshik did you apply my changes exactly? I renamed `client` argument to `client_coroutine` and added `client = await client_coroutine` to your func. It works fine with these changes.

Comment: Yes, I changed this part, the error did not disappear

Comment: @MehduSadeghi when adding await to create_client (number), it gives an error, which I pointed out in update 2

Comment: @danilshik try my last update. It works fine. I tried it with a real telegram api.

Comment: If it works for you, then why doesn't it work for me? Update 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185839/discussion-between-mehdi-sadeghi-and-danilshik).